# Accessing the Serial Port in Linux in C

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux, uart, usb-drive

I am trying to write and read data through serial port to a USB device in linux.I am able to write the data but I am not read the complete data that the USB device is sending to me.The underlying code is mine.Please do point out any mistake if so.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<termios.h>
#include<unistd.h>

#define SERIAL_PORT_PATH "/dev/ttyACM0"

struct termios SerialPortSettings; 

unsigned char Buffer[256] = {0X01,0X04,0X00,0X4B,0x01,0XB1};

int Serial_Port_Descriptor = 0;
int Open_flag = O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY;
int Set_Nonblock_Open_flag();
int Serial_Port_Configuring();
int Read_Serial_Port();

int main()
{
  Serial_Port_Descriptor = open(SERIAL_PORT_PATH,Open_flag);
  if(Serial_Port_Descriptor > 0)
   {
     printf("Serial_Port has been Opened \n");
     Set_Nonblock_Open_flag();
   }
 else
   {
     perror("Error:");
   }
  Serial_Port_Configuring();
  write(Serial_Port_Descriptor,&Buffer,sizeof(Buffer));
  sleep(2);
  while(1)
  {
    Read_Serial_Port();
  } 
  close(Serial_Port_Descriptor);
  return 0;
}

int Set_Nonblock_Open_flag()
{
  Open_flag = fcntl(Serial_Port_Descriptor,F_GETFL,Open_flag);
  if(Open_flag == -1)
   {
     return -1;
   }
  else if (0)
   {
     Open_flag |= O_NONBLOCK;
     printf("The Flag is set to Nonblock \n");
   }
  else
   {
     Open_flag &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
   }
  return fcntl(Serial_Port_Descriptor,F_SETFL,Open_flag);
}

int Serial_Port_Configuring()
{ 
  tcgetattr(Serial_Port_Descriptor,&SerialPortSettings);

  cfsetispeed(&SerialPortSettings,B115200); 
  cfsetospeed(&SerialPortSettings,B115200); 

  SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;             
  SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;            
  SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;           
  SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |= CS8;          
  SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;   
  SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL; 
  SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
  SerialPortSettings.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHONL | ISIG | IEXTEN); 
  SerialPortSettings.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; /* No Ouptut Processing */

  SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;   /* Read atleast 1 character */
  SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; /* Wait Indefinitely */

  tcflush(Serial_Port_Descriptor,TCIOFLUSH);

  if(tcsetattr(Serial_Port_Descriptor,TCSANOW,&SerialPortSettings) != 0)
   {
     printf("Error: The Settings are not been Configured \n");
     return -1;
   }
   else
   {
     printf("Settings have been Configured \n");
   }
  return 0;
}

int Read_Serial_Port()
{
  int Serial_Port_Read = read(Serial_Port_Descriptor,&Buffer,sizeof(Buffer));
  if(Serial_Port_Read < 0)
   {
     fputs("Read of bytes() has failed \n",stderr);
     return -1;
   }
  else if(Serial_Port_Read > 0)
   {
     printf("%d bytes has been read \n",Serial_Port_Read);
     for(int i=0;i <= Serial_Port_Read;i++)
      {
        printf("%02X",(unsigned char)Buffer[i]); 
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you do "not read the complete data"?

Comment: I am only able to read the first byte of the received data.The terminal remains blank.So I terminate the process and run again.

Comment: "I am not read the complete data". Please be more specific. Please provide the exact expected output and actual output. BTW, your code is in a busy loop calling `read`. That is very CPU intensive and not usually the recommended way - better to use BLOCK and then `select`.

Comment: To be more specific I write 6 bytes of data to the port and in turn read  only 1 byte whereas I have to read nearly about 10 bytes of it.

Comment: Is that the buffer is getting cleared before I read the data?

Comment: `Return_Value` is used uninitialized in **Set_Nonblock_Open_flag()**.  The **write()** and **read()** syscalls use the *address* of the array address.

Comment: Your `printf` in `Read_Serial_Port` doesn't flush the data you send to it. Either add '\n' or `fflush`. Also you're trying to print 1 extra byte - replace `<=` in loop condition with `<` to fix that.

Comment: In `printf` use `\n` or flush the buffer